# Trying to install OpenLDAP with TLS

Tags: openldap

I have OpenLDAP set up with a GoDaddy SSL certificate installed. A non-secure LDAP search works fine. But when I do this: `ldapsearch -x -b dc=yln,dc=info -Z`, I get this:

```
ldap_start_tls: Connect error (-11)
ldap_result: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

If I run the command as root, it works.

Here's my ldif file:

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.args
olcLogLevel: none
olcPidFile: /var/run/openldap/slapd.pid
olcTLSCACertificatePath: /etc/openldap/certs
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/openldap/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/openldap/certs/yln.key
olcToolThreads: 1
structuralObjectClass: olcGlobal
entryUUID: 940013a0-3521-1034-9ed9-875b6f3874a7
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20150120185459Z
entryCSN: 20220801163425.157759Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20220801163425Z
```

And here's my certificate files:

```
-rw-------  1 ldap ldap  2317 Aug 12 12:51 1d40117d24e9b169.pem
-r--------  1 ldap ldap  1708 Aug 12 11:52 yln.key
```

I have added `ldaps:///` to the slapd file and in ldap.conf, I've added:

```
TLS_CACERT    /etc/openldap/certs/1d40117d24e9b169.pem
TLS_REQCERT   allow
```

I'm to the point of beating my head against the wall. Is it a permissions issue or something else?

Comment: Your `ldapsearch` command line doesn't specify a host to which to connect. Do you get the same behavior if you explicitly pass `-H ldaps://<yourhostname>:<ssl_port>`?

Comment: Or try adding `-d1` to the command line; this will show you the name of the server to which it is connecting.

Comment: @roaima That was it. I change the public cert to 644 and now everything works. Thank you!

Comment: @Chanel I've converted that to an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that "*If I run the command as root, it works.*"

This indicates a permissions issue. Your client probably can't access a configuration file (or certificate file) that it needs. The public certificate should be world readable - it is by definition public knowledge. The private certificate should be accessible only by the server process.